# How to fetch data from postgres existing tables to Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a Postgres Database and it has plenty of tables in it, using Django I need to query or get all the table rows into my views.py. After reading I understood that creating a model in models.py will create a new table into my DB which is not what I need.

Is using django a good way to fetch data from postgres or should I use the python library to communicate with postgres directly (`psycopg2`)?

If django has a way to fetch data from table then how do I do it?

Comment: Django can create models from your existing database. The [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/legacy-databases/) provide a step-by-step guide.

Comment: postgres://username:password@localhost:port/dbname

Comment: You can create a model over an existing table without Django trying to create the table by setting [managed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#managed) in the model Meta options to `False`. Read the link for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the existing database schema by

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

for adding the database model to models.py

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```